# Check all properties in list of objects is equal

Tags: c#, linq

Seems I am checking if the `Id` are all equal in a round-about way, is there a more succinct and easy to understand way to do the check?

Something like a full outer join and checking for nulls?

Specifically this part:

```
if (masters1.Count() != masters1.Intersect(masters2).Count())
{
    throw new Exception("one IDs did not match two IDs");
}

if (masters2.Count() != masters2.Intersect(masters3).Count())
{
    throw new Exception("two IDs did not match three IDs");
}
```

Full example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;


        public class Record
        {
            public string Id;
            public string Value;
        }

        public class Records
        {
            public Record One;
            public Record Two;
            public Record Three;
        }

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var one = new List<Record>(){new Record(){Id = "one", Value = "1"},new Record(){Id = "two", Value = "2"}};
        var two = new List<Record>(){new Record(){Id = "one", Value = "1"},new Record(){Id = "two", Value = "2"}};
        var three = new List<Record>(){new Record(){Id = "one", Value = "1"},new Record(){Id = "two", Value = "2"}};

        var masters1 = one.Select(x => x.Id);
        var masters2 = two.Select(x => x.Id);
        var masters3 = three.Select(x => x.Id);


        if (masters1.Count() != masters1.Intersect(masters2).Count())
        {
            throw new Exception("one IDs did not match two IDs");
        }

        if (masters2.Count() != masters2.Intersect(masters3).Count())
        {
            throw new Exception("two IDs did not match three IDs");
        }

        var rv = new List<Records>();
        foreach (var master in masters1)
        {
            var record = new Records()
            {
                One = one.Single(x => x.Id == master),
                Two = two.Single(x => x.Id == master),
                Three = three.Single(x => x.Id == master),
            };

            rv.Add(record);
        }


        foreach(var x in rv){
            Console.WriteLine(x.One.Value); 
            Console.WriteLine(x.Two.Value); 
            Console.WriteLine(x.Three.Value);   
        }

    }
}
```

See here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/QtjM7x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIU, you need something like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb348567(v=vs.110).aspx).
So the code will be like the following:

```
if (masters1.SequenceEqual(masters2)) DoSomething();
```

Note that SequenceEqual uses the default equality comparers, so you need to override Equals() in order to add custom comparison logic.

Comment: Because masters1 and masters2 are just a list of strings, then no need to make a custom Equals , right?

Comment: Yep! In your case - exactly :)

Comment: But you could also override Equals() in your Record class - so you won't need those .Select(x => x.Id) calls